# JTextArea I want to make my part of text bold or cursive

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I have a problem with JTextArea. I dont know how can I change part of my text in JTextArea to be bold or to be cursive. Anyone?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html

Comment: Post what you've already tried to do, d.p.

Comment: Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Simple Attributes` to change the text font and color. like

```
SimpleAttributeSet attrSet= new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setFontFamily(attrSet, "Courier New Italic");
StyleConstants.setForeground(attrSet, Color.BLUE);

textArea.getDocument().insertString(0, "Your text is here", attrSet);
```

and alternatively, you will get much more [advantage and flexibility, if you use editor or text panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html).

Comment: Thx, Styled Text Areas are much better than Plain Text Areas.